# Excel VBA macro that will copy a range of cells and paste into another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro for a spreadsheet that will import values from the first column of another spreadsheet. I've found a macro that will do it manually, but I would like to make it an automatic process if possible so that it will update with just a click of a button. Below is the original macro I found:

```
    Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
        Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
        Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
        Dim rngSourceRange As Range
        Dim rngDestination As Range
        Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Show
            If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
                Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
                Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
                wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
                Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
                rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
                rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                wkbSourceBook.Close False
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

I've done a bit of editing, but since I don't really know VBA I'm kind of stuck. This is where I'm at right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
         Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
         Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
         Dim rngSourceRange As Range
         Dim rngDestination As Range
         Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
         With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
             .Filters.Clear
             .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
             .AllowMultiSelect = False
             .Show
             If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                 Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
                 Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
                 Set rngSourceRange = Range(A2:A500)
                 wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
                 Set rngDestination = Range(A2)
                 rngSourceRange.Copy
                 rngDestination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                 rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                 wkbSourceBook.Close False
             End If
         End With
     End Sub
```

The end of the range doesn't have to be 500, I just want to make sure I capture all of the values that will be in the range right now and for the future. If there is also a way to make the macro only select cells that have data in the column (B) next to it, I would love to hear some suggestions!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")

Dim LastRowS1CA As Long
Dim LastRowS2CA As Long

LastRowS1CA = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & LastRowS1CA).Copy '<=== Copy Range from Workbook Book 1 sheet1

LastRowS2CA = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRowS2CA).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False '<=== Paste range to workbook Book 2 sheet2

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. So I'm wanting to take only row A as the range, and it's from another workbook entirely. Is there something that I would change in that 4th line to get that to pull from another workbook?

Comment: It says that the workbook is out of my range. I've never really coded in VBA so I could be totally ruining a perfectly good code

Comment: Make sure that you check workbooks and sheets names (change if needed)